# Where should be put the @Configuration class?

Tags: spring-boot

I am new to Spring Boot. I saw [a blog](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-jpa-mysql-sample-app-code-example) to use JPA with Spring Boot. There is the `@Configuration` class MySQLAppConfig in the document. It does not tell where is the file created ! So where should the `@Configuration` class be placed ?

Comment: Did my answer helped? If yes, consider accepting it, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be picked by [ComponentScan](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-configuration-classes.html)

> You need not put all your @Configuration into a single class. The @Import annotation can be used to import additional configuration classes. Alternatively, you can use @ComponentScan to automatically pick up all Spring components, including @Configuration classes.

Or register class as an [auto-configuration candidate](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-auto-configuration):

> The next mandatory step is registering the class as an auto-configuration candidate, by adding the name of the class under the key org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration in the standard file resources/META-INF/spring.factories:
>
> ```
>  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=
> ```